# Find maximum numbers from n-Numpy array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is there a way to find out the highest individual numbers give a list of Numpy arrays?

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10, 2])
b = np.array([3, 4])
c = np.array([5, 6])
```

The output will be a Numpy array with the following form:

```
np.array([10, 6])
```

Comment: Are the arrays all of the same shape?

Comment: yes. they are in same shape

Answer (score 2):

You can stack all arrays together and get the max afterwards:

```
np.stack((a, b, c)).max(0)
# array([10,  6])
```